# asyncpg.Cursor.fetch() extremely slow when fetching from a large table

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2, asyncpg

So initially I was using a very inefficient method of fetching results from a database table and I thought cursors would be faster and more efficient.

```
async with db.acquire() as conn:
    query = "SELECT * FROM table"
    records = []
    async with conn.transaction():
        cur = await pconn.cursor(query, *args)
        for i in range(10):
            records.append(await cur.fetch(20))
```

The problem is, the `for loop` takes forever to complete, which I suppose is because `await cur.fetch()` is extremely slow
My table has about 7-8 million records

Comment: Why `for i in range(10)`? Do you only want the first 10 rows? If so just add `LIMIT 10` to the end of your query. Be sure to add an `ORDER BY` though so you get consistent results.

Comment: No, not the first 10 rows

Comment: I'm doing it so it adds 20 rows 10 times to the `records` list

Comment: So you still only want a tiny fraction of the table? That is you only want  200 of  7=9 million of rows in your table? In that case use the `LIMIT` clause. It allows the database to terminate the query early rather than fetch every single row and transmit it over the network,

Comment: I see @Dunes, Okay I'll try that

Comment: @Dunes I'm afraid it wasn't solved, it still takes a long time to complete (if it even completes)... Here is a sample query `SELECT * FROM products WHERE shipper = 'DHL' ORDER BY price ASC LIMIT 200
`

Comment: Is there an index on the shipper column? The easiest way to find out is to type `\d+ products` in psql. If not, then you'll want to create one eg. `CREATE INDEX ON products (shipper);`

Comment: After creating the index it works perfect! Thanks man, but may I ask what exactly is the need for indexes, what it does and why is such a helpful feature not added by default?

Comment: Imagine you're in a library, and books are just on random shelves (your **table**). You want to find out who wrote "The Hobbit" (a **query**). You'd have to check all the books in the library randomly until you found the book. An **index** on title would be an alphabetical list of all books by title saying exactly where to find each book in the library. Meaning, you can quickly search the index, find the books with the right title and then go find them and check who the author is. And if the index is big, then you can use binary search to find the right titles (as it is sorted).

Comment: I see, makes so much sense now, Thanks!!